# How do I position my text field properly in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program which spawns a second window and I want the text field to be closer to 'Name: ' but I don't know how to go about it.

```
def editWindow():

item_choice_intvar = tk.IntVar()
course_choice_intvar  = tk.IntVar()

editMenu = tk.Toplevel()
editMenu.geometry('400x400')
editMenu.resizable(False,False)
editMenu['bg'] = 'black'
editMenu.title('Configure Menu')

addItem = tk.Label(editMenu,text = "Add Item:",font = ("Garamond",20),bg = 'black')
addItem.grid(column = 0,row = 0, sticky = 'WN', pady = 10, padx = 20)

itemChoice = tk.Radiobutton(editMenu,text = 'Menu Item',variable=item_choice_intvar,value = 1,bg = 'black') 
dealChoice = tk.Radiobutton(editMenu,text = 'Special Deal',variable=item_choice_intvar,value = 2,bg = 'black')
itemChoice.grid(column = 0,row=1)
dealChoice.grid(column = 1,row=1)

courseText = tk.Label(editMenu,text = "Select Course:",font = ("Garamond",20),bg = 'black')
courseText.grid(column = 0,row = 2, sticky = 'N', pady = 10, padx = 20)

entreeChoice = tk.Radiobutton(editMenu,text = 'Entree',variable=course_choice_intvar,value = 1,bg = 'black') 
mainChoice = tk.Radiobutton(editMenu,text = 'Main',variable=course_choice_intvar,value = 2,bg = 'black')
dessertChoice = tk.Radiobutton(editMenu,text = 'Dessert',variable=course_choice_intvar,value = 3,bg = 'black') 

entreeChoice.grid(column = 0, row = 3)
mainChoice.grid(column = 1, row = 3,sticky = 'W')
dessertChoice.grid(column = 2, row = 3,sticky = 'W')

itemNameText = tk.Label(editMenu,text = 'Name: ',font = ("Garamond",15),bg = 'black')
nameTextField = tk.Text(editMenu,height=1,width=15)
itemNameText.grid(column = 0, row = 4,sticky='W',padx = 25,pady = 30)
nameTextField.grid(column = 1, row = 4,sticky = 'W')
```

I've tried using sticky and pad but they don't seem to be helping.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put the label and text box inside another frame:

```py
def editWindow():
    ...
    # frame to hold the label and text box
    frame = tk.Frame(editMenu, bg='black')
    frame.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='W')

    itemNameText = tk.Label(frame, text='Name:', font=("Garamond",15), bg= 'black', fg='white')
    nameTextField = tk.Text(frame, height=1, width=15) # why not use Entry widget instead?
    itemNameText.pack(side='left', padx=25, pady=30)
    nameTextField.pack(side='left')
```

Result:

[image]